# Performance is very bad when set label with Thai text in Unity

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I have a Button in a Canvas, and when I set text button with English text, it works correct, but when set with Thai text, it delays up to 6 seconds (bad performance).

First I thought it was because I load many sounds and images, but after removing all of them, it's still slow, and if I change my Thai text, it works fast.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

```
public Text text;

void Start () {

    text.text = "เพลงจิ้งจก";

}
```

I tried changing the font (Thonburi font), but no affect. So, my solution is change that text to image, which is a bad solution but cannot find any useful ways.

Comment: Try to fill text field in inspector with every char that this font contains.

Comment: It's the same problem when I input that text in inspector.
it run rather fast in editor but really slow in iOS. after changing load image instead of that text, that problem is fixed.

Comment: Here [link](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/4-6-3-dynamic-font-rendering-performance-issues-on-ios.299220/) i found something about text performacne on iOS, maybe that helps.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It seems this is a Unity bug. I will try with TextMeshPro and see how it work.
Thanks

Comment: @PawełMarecki It might be worth posting your comment as an answer (make sure to include all relevant information from the link, not just the link itself).

Comment: I had a similar issue a while ago, I remember I only had the delay if the text was changed from latin to unicode characters via code. but if the text was unicode characters from set from the inspector than I could change to latin and back with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Last version of Unity has some performance issue on asian font due frequent call of `iphone::GetFontPath()` in `RequestCharactersInTexture`

A possible solution is track all characters used on application (I have script that do it) and set a special font as `custom set` with all characters used.

It is very hard to maintain but boost performance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hacky method, but if you only have a few lines of text that you need and they can be determined ahead of time, you could just load all of them on startup with a transparent color or off screen, then change the color or move it in when you need it.